# Binary Bomb Phase 5 issue (my phase 5 seems to be different from everyone elses)

Tags: assembly, x86

So I am working on a Binary Bomb assignment and have gotten stuck. Tried looking at other questions and guides but mine seems to be completely different from what is described in other questions and guides I found on the web.

The phase only takes 2 unsigned ints for input. Here it is disassembled in gdb after being run with 11 2 as input.

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
0x08048ccc <+0>:     push   %ebp
0x08048ccd <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048ccf <+3>:     push   %esi
0x08048cd0 <+4>:     push   %ebx
=> 0x08048cd1 <+5>:     sub    $0x20,%esp
0x08048cd4 <+8>:     lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x08048cd7 <+11>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
0x08048cdb <+15>:    lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048cde <+18>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x08048ce2 <+22>:    movl   $0x8049b0a,0x4(%esp)
0x08048cea <+30>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048ced <+33>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048cf0 <+36>:    call   0x8048788 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x08048cf5 <+41>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
0x08048cf8 <+44>:    jg     0x8048cff <phase_5+51>
0x08048cfa <+46>:    call   0x80492b6 <explode_bomb>
0x08048cff <+51>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048d02 <+54>:    and    $0xf,%eax
0x08048d05 <+57>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048d08 <+60>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
0x08048d0b <+63>:    je     0x8048d36 <phase_5+106>
0x08048d0d <+65>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
0x08048d12 <+70>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
0x08048d17 <+75>:    mov    $0x8049960,%ebx
0x08048d1c <+80>:    add    $0x1,%edx
0x08048d1f <+83>:    mov    (%ebx,%eax,4),%eax
0x08048d22 <+86>:    add    %eax,%ecx
0x08048d24 <+88>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
0x08048d27 <+91>:    jne    0x8048d1c <phase_5+80>
0x08048d29 <+93>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048d2c <+96>:    cmp    $0xb,%edx
0x08048d2f <+99>:    jne    0x8048d36 <phase_5+106>
0x08048d31 <+101>:   cmp    -0x10(%ebp),%ecx
0x08048d34 <+104>:   je     0x8048d3b <phase_5+111>
0x08048d36 <+106>:   call   0x80492b6 <explode_bomb>
0x08048d3b <+111>:   add    $0x20,%esp
0x08048d3e <+114>:   pop    %ebx
0x08048d3f <+115>:   pop    %esi
0x08048d40 <+116>:   pop    %ebp
0x08048d41 <+117>:   ret
```

For the line  0x08048d17 <+75>:    mov    $0x8049960,%ebx

I used

x/16b 0x8049960

gdb and it tells me

0x8049960 array.2954: 10      0       0       0       2       0       0      0

0x8049968 array.2954+8:       14      0       0       0       7       0      00

When I go through the program using until until I get to

0x08048d31 <+101>:   cmp    -0x10(%ebp),%ecx

%edx = 11, %ecx = 82, and %ebp-0x10 = 2 (used print to get values for first two and x/d $ebp-0x10 for last one)

Because 82 != 2 it just goes to call explode_bomb.

From what I understand it is reading in my 2 numbers, making sure I entered 2 at <+41>.
Then it grabs the first number from the array which in this case is 10 and puts it into $eax at +=<+51>. Then it puts eax into -0xc($ebp) at <+57>.

Then it checks to make sure $eax isn't 15 at <+60>, goes on to set $ecx, and $edx to 0. It then passes the pointer to the array to $ebx at <+75>.

Then it enters a loop from <+80> to <+91> but I am not sure what it is really doing. I get that it increments $edx by 1 and the loop is exited when $eax is 15, but I cant figure out how the rest of the stuff works out.

Am I understanding it correctly up to the loop part? And, if someone wouldn't mind explaining what is happening between <+80> and <+91> I would be very grateful.

p.s. Sorry if my formatting is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then it grabs the first number from the array which in this case is
>   10 and puts it into $eax at +=<+51>.

Wrong. `<+51>` reads the first number you entered, not the first number from the array. It's then masked into the 0..15 range by discarding the top bits, and is written back to the local variable where it came from. It also lives on in `eax`, of course.

The array contains 4 byte integers and there are 15 of them. As such you can print it using `x/15wd`.

Now to the loop. `edx` is obviously just keeping track of the iteration count, no surprise there. `<+83>` is the interesting part: it replaces `eax` with the value of the array item whose index `eax` currently holds. That is `eax = array[eax]`. `ecx` is of course just summing up the array elements you have visited, that's again easy. The exit condition is when you hit the array item that has value 15.

What it all boils down is that this array is really a linked list. The end of the list is marked by a 15. The first number you enter is used as a starting point for list traversal. It should be selected such that you have 11 elements until the end of the list (see `<+96>`). The second input number should equal the sum of the array items visited.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, managed to get it to work after reading your corrections.

Comment: Excuse me! I have found this answer very helpful. However, I still have some questions. First, by mask you mean that the program will apply a mask to our first input, right? If so in order to make it able to traverse 11 elements then when we enter the first inputer, we should also calculate it with mask first, right? Second, for example if the array is [10, 2, 14, 7, 8, 12, 15, 11, 0, 4, 1, 13, 3, 9, 6, 5], then in order to make it traverse 11 elements and end up at the 15, we have to start at element which value is 3? Let's me know if my questions are not clear. Thank so much!

Comment: The way I counted that's 12 steps not 11 but I may be off by one :)