# Assembly Language Bomb Lab

Tags: assembly, gdb, disassembly

I have tried looking for similar bombs with similar assembly and I cant seem to find one. I am having trouble with this phase specifically what is going on at line <70>. Here is my assembly and below are my findings:

```
   0x00000000004011f1 <+0>: sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x00000000004011f5 <+4>: lea    0xc(%rsp),%rcx
   0x00000000004011fa <+9>: lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdx
   0x00000000004011ff <+14>:    mov    $0x402af1,%esi
   0x0000000000401204 <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000401209 <+24>:    callq  0x400cb0 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x000000000040120e <+29>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000401211 <+32>:    jg     0x401218 <phase_5+39>
   0x0000000000401213 <+34>:    callq  0x401785 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401218 <+39>:    mov    0x8(%rsp),%eax
   0x000000000040121c <+43>:    and    $0xf,%eax
   0x000000000040121f <+46>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%rsp)
   0x0000000000401223 <+50>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
   0x0000000000401226 <+53>:    je     0x401254 <phase_5+99>
   0x0000000000401228 <+55>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x000000000040122d <+60>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x0000000000401232 <+65>:    add    $0x1,%edx
   0x0000000000401235 <+68>:    cltq   
   0x0000000000401237 <+70>:    mov    0x402820(,%rax,4),%eax
   0x000000000040123e <+77>:    add    %eax,%ecx
   0x0000000000401240 <+79>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
   0x0000000000401243 <+82>:    jne    0x401232 <phase_5+65>
   0x0000000000401245 <+84>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%rsp)
   0x0000000000401249 <+88>:    cmp    $0xf,%edx
   0x000000000040124c <+91>:    jne    0x401254 <phase_5+99>
   0x000000000040124e <+93>:    cmp    0xc(%rsp),%ecx
   0x0000000000401252 <+97>:    je     0x401259 <phase_5+104>
   0x0000000000401254 <+99>:    callq  0x401785 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401259 <+104>:   add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x000000000040125d <+108>:   retq enter code here
```

I know that the function taking two integers. The first one entered is at rdx and the second one is at rcx. It then puts the first integer into eax <39> after it makes sure two numbers were inputted.

<43> It then takes the least significant bit of eax with a bitwise and and stores it in eax

<46> the new value of eax is then stored in the original location of the first integer.

<50> eax is compared with 15 and if its less than 15 the program continue

<55,60> ecx and edx are now 0

<65> we start a loop edx is the index and 1 is added to it before starting the loop.

<70> I am not sure what exactly is happening here mov    0x402820(,%rax,4),%eax but i know that it is changing the value of eax

<77> adds the summ of eax and ecx (im not sure how ecx ever gets a value as it was already set at 0 <55> and there is no change up until this instruction

<79>checks if eax = 15 if it doesnt the loop reruns

<88>when eax is 15 it then checks if the loop counter edx has been run 15 times

<93> compares the second int entered to ecx which i beleive eax would equal to eax from line <77>

any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: <70> says to move the 32 bit integer from memory addresss (0x402820+%rax*4) and move it to %eax. AT&T syntax is _segment:displacement(base register, offset register, scalar multiplier)_ . You can learn more about this addressing [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax) under the section _Address operand syntax_

Comment: So when this loop keeps running will the same memory address be continually stored into eax? if so how can I find out what is at that memory address (0x402820+%rax*4)

Comment: 64 bit [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400388/binary-bomb-phase-5-issue-my-phase-5-seems-to-be-different-from-everyone-elses/23400601) with a slight variation.

Comment: thank you i figured it out!